# How does Storm know when a message is "fully processed"?

Tags: apache-storm

(Also a couple of questions about timeouts and maxSpoutPending)

I see a lot of references in the Storm documentation about messages being fully processed. But how does my KafkaSpout know when a message is fully processed?

Hopefully it is cognizant of the way my bolts are connected so when the final bolt in my Stream acks a tuple, the spout knows when my message is processed?

Otherwise, I would imagine that after the timeout period expires, the ack-ed state of a message is checked, and it is considered processed if indicated by the acking/anchoring XORs. But I hope this is not the case?

I also have related questions about maxTuplesPending and timeout configuration.

If I set the maxTuplePending to 10k, then am I correct in thinking each spout instance will continue to emit tuples until that spout instance is tracking 10k tuples in flight, 10k tuples that have not been fully processed? And then a new tuple is emitted when a currently in flight message is fully processed?

And finally, does this relate to the timeout configuration? Do the spouts wait in any fashion for the configured timeout to occur before emitting new messages?Or does the timeout configuration only come into play if a message is stalled/slow in being processed, resulting in it getting failed due to timeout?

More succinctly (or hopefully more clearly), is there an effect to setting my timeout to 30 mins other than messages won't be failed unless they are ack-ed by the final Bolt within 30 mins? Or are there other impacts, such as the timeout configuration effecting the emission rate of the spouts?

Sorry for the long, rambling question(s). Thanks in advance for any response.

*Edit to clarify further

The reason this is a concern for me, is because my messages don't necessarily run through the entire Stream.

Say I have Bolts A, B, C, D. Most of the time messages will get passed from A->B->->D. But I have some messages that intentionally will stop on bolt A. A will ack them but not emit them (because of my business logic, in those cases I do want further processing of the messages).

So will my KafkaSpout know that the message which is ack-ed but not emitted from A is fully processed? As I would like another message to be emitted from the spout as soon as Bolt A is done with it, in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Storm tracks the tuples throughout the whole topology via the anchoring mechanism that the UDF code must use. This anchoring results in so-called tuple-tree, were the root of the tree is the tuple emitted by the spout and all other nodes (that are connected in a tree structure) represent the emitted tuples from bolts **that used input tuples as anchors** (this is only a logical model and not implemented this way in Storm, though).

For example, a Spout emit a sentence tuple that is split by the first bolt in words, some word are filtered by the second bolt, and a word count is applied by the third bolt. Finally, a sink bolt writes the result into file. The tree would look like this:

```
"this is an example sentence" -+-> "this" 
                               +-> "is" 
                               +-> "an"
                               +-> "example" -> "example",1 -> "example",1
                               +-> "sentence" -> "sentence",1 -> "sentence",1
```

The initial sentence is emitted by spout, used as anchor by bolt1 for all tokens that are emitted, and gets acked by bolt1. Bolt2 filters out "this", "is" and "an" and just acks the three tuples. "example" and "sentence" are just forwarded, used as anchor for the output tuple and acked afterwards. Same happens in bolt2, and the final sink bolt just acks all incoming tuples.

Furthermore, Storm tracks all acks of all tuples, ie, from intermediate bolts as well as sink bolts. First, the spout sends the ID of the output tuple to an acker task. Each time a tuple is used as anchor, the acker also get a message with the anchor tuple ID and the output tuple ID (which in auto generated by Storm). The ackes from the bolt also go to the same acker task that XORs them. If all acks got received -- ie, for the spout and all recursively anchored output tuples -- (the XOR result will be zero), the acker send a message to the spout that the tuple is fully processed and the backcall to `Spout.ack(MessageId)` happens (ie, the back call is done immediately when the tuple is fully processed). Furthermore, the ackers check regularly, if there is a tuple that is registered by the acker longer than the timeout. If this happens, the tuple ID is dropped by the acker and a message is sent to the spout that the tuple failed (resulting in a call to `Spout.fail(MessageId)`).

Furthermore, the Spouts keep a count of all tuple in flight and stop calling `Spout.nextTuple()` if this count exceeds `maxTuplesPending` parameter. As far as I know, the parameter is applied in globally, ie, the local counts of each spout tasks are summed up and the global count is compared to the parameter (not sure how this in implemented in detail though).

So the `timeout` parameter is independent from `maxTuplesPending`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. Could you address the scenario I mentioned in the Edit. How does Storm know that "all acks have been received". If I intentionally ack after bolt A, but do not emit the tuple to bolt B, will that message timeout?

Comment: Look at my example. the tuples "this", "is", and "an" will be filtered out by an intermediate bolt, ie, only acked and no output. This works just fine. If all words from a sentence would be filtered, the tree is just less deep, but the initial sentence will get acked just fine to the spout.

Comment: Thanks again. I do remain confused as to how Storm handles this. If bolt A calls ack and doesn't emit, how does Storm know to call Spout.ack(messageId)? I would think it would only call Spout.ack(messageId) when a tuple is ack-ed by the final bolt in the Tuple tree (how could it know that in this case, where I didn't emit, that the tree is less deep than typical). I ask this because I am seeing spout failures even though my topology is fully processing it's messages within the timeout time, so i suspect the failures are coming from those messages that Bolt A ack-ed but didn't emit.

Comment: Minor answer update. To address your question here: if a bolt does not emit, there is no anchoring happening, ie, the input tuple is not used as anchor. Thus, Storm knows, that the tuple is a leaf tuple in the tuple tree. The Spout.ack call happens if all acks from the bolt are received. There is actually no requirement on the order of the ack call. If you for example buffer an input tuple in a bolt and you do not ack it right away, this is absolutely fine. For example, you want to buffer and process it if a second "matching" input tuple arrives. In this later processing step, you ack both.

Comment: Don't think of the acking in a hierarchical or timely ordered manner. Think with **set semantics**. Each time a spout emits a tuple, a new set containing this tuple is produced. Each time a tuple is used as an anchor, the output tuple it added to the set of the anchor tuple. Acking removes tuple from the set (the order is not important). If the set gets empty, `Spout.ack` is called. If the set is not empty after the timeout (that start when the set is created), `Spout.fail` is called (and the set is dropped).

Comment: Thanks again for all the information and effort, this all makes sense (mostly). I remain slightly confused, possibly I could explain the scenario that is confusing to me: Spout emits a tuple, the set now has one anchor in it. I receive and ack the tuple, the set is now empty. I might soon emit the tuple, adding a new achor to the set. How does storm know to wait to call Spout.ack? Wouldn't it detect the empty set when I first ack the tuple?

Comment: Your observation is correct. After a tuple is acked, you cannot use it as an anchor anymore. Thus, as long as you want to use a tuple as an anchor, you need to defer the ack call in the corresponding bolt.

Comment: OH! (eureka). That is what I'm currently doing, anchoring/emitting and then acking. And it all makes sense now. Thanks again for this lengthy and very helpful discussion.